# installing the app in the emulator, keeps installing

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, android-manifest, adp

I have this app. It works fine on my phone and it used to work fine on the emulator.
But when I did an update of Eclipse to Android API 15, the trouble started.

If I want to run my app on the emulator i get the following output in my Console

`[2012-01-18 09:12:21 - ] Android Launch!

    [2012-01-18 09:12:21 - ] adb is running normally.

    [2012-01-18 09:12:21 - ] Performing  activity launch

    [2012-01-18 09:12:26 - ] Uploading .apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

    [2012-01-18 09:12:59 - ] Installing .apk...`

the top part of the manifest:

    `[manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.visualreality.sportapp" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.2"]
    [uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /]
    [uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/]
    [uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /]
    [uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"][/uses-permission]
    [uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"][/uses-permission]

    [uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" /]`

(i changed the "<>" to "[]", didn't know how to make those tags visible)

And it keeps installing. And the app will not start on my emulator.
when I copy the .apk file to my phone, it works, so no errors in my code.

Can someone help please?

**update**
In Eclipse I have build the .apk file.
I then install the apk file in the emulator via de CMD:
using the adb.exe in /android-sdk-windows/platform-tools

`adb -s emulator-5554 install -r /path/to/your/apkfile.apk`

After that you can run the application from the application menu in the emulator.

Comment: also paste your manifest

Comment: edited the questoin with the top of the manifest

Comment: have your provided correct intent filters to your main activity for e.g. `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>`

Comment: yes I did. The app worked just fine before the update. I also made a complete new HelloWorld Project, which has the same problem. It uploads the app to the emulator, it starts installing and keeps installing.

Comment: add a new emulation device and try

Comment: nope sorry..tried that as well :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, restart the emulator if you haven't tried that, I've experienced that the install process gets stuck sometimes.

Second, there were pretty large changes made to the build scripts in revision 14 of the SDK tools ([change log](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14)), this might cause some trouble if you updated from a previous version. Are you launching your app on the emulator inside Eclipse or from the command line?

Edit: looks like you're running from inside eclipse. Try launching from the command line by entering this command from your project root (which contains build.xml):

> ant debug install

If this doesn't work, you might have to manually upgrade the project by running the following command:

**DISCLAIMER:** By doing the following you might lose any customizations to your build.xml file. Please backup your project first!

> android update project --path path_to_your_project

This will update your build.xml along with some property files (like ant.properties) to work with the updated build process.

Comment: the idea gave me the right direction. It somewhat works, need to make a script I think. I give you the points, but I will post the answer I have as well

Comment: Glad to at least point you in the right direction, hope you find a good solution!

Comment: still a drag that I need to run scripts which take 2 times as long as what I used to do in eclipse... :(